# sql query to sum the columns of 2 table based on the column whose data is different

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

after putting a lot of effort in making the sql query i ended up in the mess,what i have done so far is this is the table1

```
select bill_no='2016-2017', B_id, COALESCE(sum(amount-gr),0) as amount, COALESCE (sum(tax),0) as tax, COALESCE(sum(amount_paid),0) as amount_paid, COALESCE(sum(gr),0) as gr,'sun4269' as forUser from tbl_addbill 
 where forUser='sun4269' and bill_date between '2016-04-01' and '2017-03-31' group by B_id;

bill_no     B_id     amount tax   amount_paid   gr  forUser
2016-2017   B-1       34875 0       0           0    sun4269
2016-2017   L-1       21014 0     19363         0    sun4269
2016-2017   P-1       10217 0       0           0    sun4269
2016-2017   S-1       30000 0    14000          0    sun4269
2016-2017   T-1       66237 0    21426          0    sun4269
```

and this s the table 2

```
select bill_no,B_id,amount,tax,amount_paid,gr,forUser from tbl_addbill where forUser='sun4269' and bill_date is null and bill_no='2015-2016'       

bill_no     B_id    amount  tax    amount_paid  gr  forUser
2015-2016   K-1     181523  0      22159        0   sun4269
2015-2016   L-1     25266   0      4644         0   sun4269
2015-2016   P-1     122383  0      122383   113162  sun4269
2015-2016   A-1     38367   1827   0            0   sun4269
2015-2016   S-1     698262  18575  577120   113449  sun4269
```

it can be seen that the column 'B_id' in table1 and in table2 has same as well as different values (L-1 is repeating but B-1 is not),what i want is if L-1 is repeating in the tables, then amount,amount_paid,tax,gr sum be summed with '2016-2017'  from both the tables and if B-1 is unique in any of the table then it should be also there with the value of '2016-2017'

Comment: There are several issues here. First you are inconsistent with aliasing your columns. Pick either = or as and stick with it. Your date strings are language specific and are likely to fail. Use ANSI standard YYYYMMDD. And between is really scary, especially when using dates. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common But most of all it is totally unclear what you want here. Give us some ddl , sample data and desired output. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: what i want is to print table 1 along with ,amount,tax,gr,amount_paid of L-1,P-1,s-1 from table 2 should be added to L-1,P-1,s-1 of table 1 and rest of(K-1,A-1) should also be added with table1 as new row

Comment: Perhaps you can take a few minutes and read the article I linked? We need details in order to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` your table1 and table2 queries, and perform `GROUP BY` and associated aggregate functions on the `UNION`'d table.

If you start with just a `UNION` of table1 and table2, you will see what I mean, because the result will be a single table will all the rows from table1 and table2; you can then add `GROUP BY B_id` and the desired aggregation functions (e.g., `SUM()`).

Comment: If the OP is wanting to combine those two queries into a single result it would be a better approach to modify there where clause because both queries are pulling from the same table.

Comment: @SeanLange  I actually agree with you, and with more information from the OP (such as the info you've suggested they provide), I might be able to offer an answer along those lines;  I offered a workable answer based on the information available;  I look forward to the day when I have enough SO rep to add comments to a question in order to give advice and ask questions of clarification -- and the way to get there is to post answers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but would some conditional aggregation help here?

```
 select..., sum(case when bill_date between '2016-04-01' and '2017-03-31'then amount-gr else null end) [2016billdata], 
 sum(case when bill_date between '2015-04-01' and '2016-03-31'then amount-gr else null end) [2015billdata]....from tbl_addbill
 group by...
```